# WooCoomerce: Automatically add product line item if another category product is present on order creation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Im trying to add products from an ACF field automatically when I manually create an order and Im adding a product within a given category, but not sure where to start.

This is what I have so far:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'add_unique_id', 10, 1 );
function add_unique_id( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_obj ) {

       
      
        $category = 'my_product_category'; 

        // If the targeted product ID or the product category is found in the order items.
        if( $item_obj->get_product_id() == $targeted_product_id || has_term( $category,'product_cat', $item_obj->get_product_id() ) ) {
        
                $product_id = get_sub_field('product', false);
                $productextra    = wc_get_product( $product_id );
                $new_product_price = 0;
                $productextra->set_price( $new_product_price );   
                $item_id =  wc_add_order_item( $productextra );    
                
   
        }
    }
}
```